# Calculate a lim $\lim_{x\to \infty } \left ( \frac{x^2+2}{x^2-4} \right)^{9x^2} $

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty } \left ( \frac{x^2+2}{x^2-4} \right)^{9x^2} 
$$

Can you help with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\left(\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^2-4}\right)^{9x^2} = \left(\left(1+\dfrac{6}{x^2-4}\right)^{x^2-4}\right)^9\cdot \left(1+\dfrac{6}{x^2-4}\right)^{36}$

Comment: Actually I think this answer is better to understand

Answer (score 5):

Using the polynomial division algorithm, rewrite the base as
$$\frac {x^2 + 2}{x^2 - 4} = 1 + \frac 6{x^2 - 4} = 1 + \frac 1 {\frac {x^2 - 4}{6}}$$

We will make use of the standard limit:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac 1x \right)^x = e$$

So:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac {x^2 + 2}{x^2 - 4}\right)^{9x^2} &= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[\left(1 + \frac 1 {\frac {x^2 - 4}{6}}\right)^{\Large\frac {x^2 - 4}{6} \cdot \frac 6 {x^2 - 4}}\right]^{9x^2}=\\
&=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[\left(1 + \frac 1 {\frac {x^2 - 4}{6}}\right)^{\Large\frac {x^2 - 4}{6}}\right]^{\Large\frac {6\cdot9x^2}{x^2 - 4}}=\\
&=e^{54}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $$A=\left ( \frac{x^2+2}{x^2-4} \right)^{9x^2}$$ and take logarithms of both sides $$\log(A)=9x^2 \log\Big(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2-4}\Big)=9x^2\log\Big(\frac{1+\frac{2}{x^2}}{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}\Big)$$ $$\log(A)=9x^2 \Big[\log \left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)-\log \left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right) \Big]$$ Now, use the fact that, for mall $y$, $$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ Apply that to each of the logarithms separately, replace $y$ by its expression as a function of $x$ (that is to say $\frac{2}{x^2}$ for the first and $\frac{-4}{x^2}$ for the second)  and simplify.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Nice technique. I always do this kind of limits algebraically. In this case I think the first term of the expansion is sufficient.

Comment: Maybe just add that we have to have $y \to 0$, to expand the logarithm, to be extra-clear?

Comment: @rubik. Yes, for sure but the advantage is that, using two terms, you can see how is approached the limit. Cheers :-)